# Inconsistencia en diseño con Report Viewer

Tags: c#, sql-server, reportviewer

Muy buenos dias compañeros. Espero la esten pasando bien. Lo siquiente es un problema que me sucede en ocasiones  y no hallo un por qué.
Normalmente cuando ya tengo mi dataset (xsd) y reporte (rdlc) diseñados creo un la forma de pantalla que contendrá el Report Writer que se asociará  los mismos y resulta algo así:
[image: Imagen editada y superpuesta para mejor entendimiento]

Pero en ocasiones sucede que obtengo;
[image: Edición y superposición para mejor entendimiento]

Aún cuando en mis revisiones todo está bien definido y existe el string de conexión (son muchas bases de datos y se cambian via software), cuando esto sucede no hay manera de crear los objetos necesarios para que funcione (al menos yo no conozco la forma).
Si alguno de ustedes les ha sucedido y han logrado solucionarlo, por favor compartan su solución, se los agradeceré eternamente por enseñarme algo que desconozco. Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontré la solución, tal vez no sea la mejor pero funciona, cuatro pasos:

- Diseña tu xsd (dataset)
- Armas tu reporte en base al dataset usando el wizard (no lo modifiques).
- Crea tu forma de pantalla contenedora del report writer y asigna el rdlc del paso 2.
- Modifica tu rdlc a como lo desees.

Y eso es todo.